# CKEditor Content rendering customization

Tags: ckeditor, html-editor

Is it possible to customize `CKEditor` content rendering?

Instead of rendering text as combination of `p` , `span` tags, we want to render in our customer format.

Is this possible through using `CKEditor` ? If yes, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible, there are several solutions:

- You can change CSS like this :

> config.contentsCss = '/css/global.css';
>   
>   http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsCss

- Use dataProcessor
- Change the enterMode

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.filter-property-enterMode

- Use BBCode plugin http://ckeditor.com/addon/bbcode

See the documentation : http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_styles

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is possible. The existing implementation that you can refer to is the official [BBCode plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/bbcode).